After mvn test I see "Tests run: 0" for some reason
i'm trying to run my tests with 'maven test', but I always receive  Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
Can't find the problem. I'm guessing that the problem is eather pom or runner
Runner does work by itself and runs all tests
package runners;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeTags;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = "cucumber.steps"
)

public class RunCucumberTest {

}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestAutomationProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!--        &lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit &ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>junit</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <version>4.12</version>-->
        <!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.12.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

<!--    <build>-->
<!--        <plugins>-->
<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                <version>3.2.5</version>-->
<!--                <configuration>-->
<!--                    <includes>-->
<!--                        <include>**/*RunCucumberTest.java</include>-->
<!--                    </includes>-->
<!--                </configuration>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->
<!--        </plugins>-->
<!--    </build>-->

</project>


I tryied a lot of changes in pom, runner, etc.. No use ;c
Tests and runner are placed in src/test/java

please post the log output ....

You're using cucumber-junit which integrates with JUnit 4.
However because you're using JUnit 5, Surefire will not run JUnit 4 tests. So you need to add the JUnit Vintage engine to have JUnit 5 run JUnit 4 or use Cucumber's JUnit 5 Engine so JUnit 5 can run Cucumber directly.
For a working example see:
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton
